# LINQ: single list which consists of multiple properties of same type of object collection

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
 var userIds = books.Select( i => new{i.CreatedById,i.ModifiedById}).Distinct();

 var lst = from i in userIds select i.CreatedById;

 var lst1 = from i in userIds select i.ModifiedById;

 var lstfinal = lst.Concat(lst1).Distinct();
```

any other way to get same result???

here: books is collection of book objects i.e. IEnumerable.

thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? so that we can easily understand. You will get result from List<list<object>>.

Comment: @AzharMansuri i want i.CreatedBy and i.ModifiedBy in a single Enumerable type..
thats what i did.. but its not an optimal solution..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternative solution - [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) from array of required properties:

```
var lstfinal = books.SelectMany(b => new [] { b.CreatedById, b.ModifiedById })
                    .Distinct();
```

Or enumerating books collection twice. [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) excludes duplicates, so you don't need to call `Distinct` (I'd go this way):

```
var lstfinal = books.Select(b => b.CreatedById)
                    .Union(books.Select(b => b.ModifiedById));
```

Comment: It is not the OP describe.

Comment: You return the pairs of `b.CreatedById, b.ModifiedById` but OP wants them in one list.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan are you sure, that SelectMany returns pairs? I'll add links to msdn for you

Comment: What is this? `new [] { b.CreatedById, b.ModifiedById }`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan that is `IEnumerable<TResult>`. Read msdn.

Comment: Yes, great! +1 Visual illusion :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yep :) SelectMany projects result into sequences and flattens sequences into single sequence

Comment: I know what does `SelectMany`, but `new[]` hit me up.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan let me check :) .. will let u know just a min

Comment: @HamletHakobyan both the lines book.select shows me  "Possible multiple enumeration of Enumerable" . its not an error just warning message from VS2012.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan second one is perfectly working :) with blue lines underlined books.select which says "Possible multiple enumeration of Enumerable".

Comment: lazyberezovsky , @HamletHakobyan.... thanks guys for your help.. i am marking this as accepted :)